# Is there a problem in a PK cryptosystem if the plaintexts are very small compared to the ciphertexts?

Tags: public-key, cryptanalysis

I'm wondering, suppose we have a public key cryptosystem $P = (pk,sk)$ such that $$pk: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^{n^2},$$ that is, the ciphertexts are $n$ times longer than the plaintexts (here, $n$ is supposed to be the **security parameter**). My question is

> Does this imply some weakness of any kind on the cryptosystem (as $n$ grows)?

It's not that I have the intuition that there may be an issue, it's just a particular property that makes me think.

**BACKGROUND**

We're developing a PK cryptosystem based in multivariate polynomial equations. So far, our ciphertexts were as long as our plaintexts, but now we have this situation, where the ciphertext / plaintext length ratio is not constant. This has its own consequences in the algebraic point of view, but in the cryptographic setting... does it have any implication? Thanks!

Comment: Having a cipher-text longer than a plaintext is actually a _feature_, as it allows you to introduce randomness and check values to dodge CPA and CCA attacks. $n^2$ is a bit too much though. Ideally you'd aim for something like $n+384$ or maybe 512 (both in bits).

Comment: @SEJPM $n + \text{constant}$ would be simply great, but we can't allow a constant in our case. Anyway, real parameters for our cryptosystem are $n\approx 50$ so $n^2 - n = 2450$. Too much, isn't it?

Comment: Well, it would require you to use like 7.5k bits to encode something like a 128-bit (150) symmetric key for hybrid encryption, which doesn't sound terribly efficient to me... (but usually there are no negative side effects to ciphertext expansion except that the ciphertext is terribly large)

Comment: Note that for [IND-CPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#IND-CPA) of any public-key encryption scheme (or even, symmetric encryption scheme with stateless encryption), ciphertexts _must_ be usually longer than plaintexts. ​ (You might have had a secure trapdoor permutation family.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: If it's asymmetric crypto, you can simply use a KEM-DEM approach, where you only use your fancy crypto to encrypt a value you derive a symmetric key from, which you use for the actual data.

Comment: @RickyDemer What do you mean with "you might have had a secure trapdoor permutation family"?

Comment: I mean [the thing you had with "ciphertext" length equal to "plaintext" length] might actually have been a secure trapdoor permutation family. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Oh ok, I got broken at the very end, so it was not that secure after all ;) Could you put your comment as an answer? I would be pleased to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. ​ ​ ​ ​ Also, note that by [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), ciphertext overhead will always be

at most ​ ​ + poly(security_parameter) , ​ ​ no matter how long the message is.

For [IND-CPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#IND-CPA) of any

public-key encryption scheme, or even

symmetric encryption scheme with stateless encryption

, ciphertexts for non-empty messages must be

overwhelmingly likely to be longer than plaintexts.

Your most recent comment suggests it was broken even in the following context, but otherwise you might have had a secure trapdoor permutation family whose domains are exactly the binary strings whose length equals the length chosen during key generation.